# DataCacheException when publishing package to cloud service

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-caching

When deploying my package to a cloud service in the Azure Portal, I have found the following problem:

[image]

All the instances are waiting for the role to start, with the following exception occurring:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException

The web roles run fine on the Compute Emulator.

I recently did add co-located caching to my system, but I have no idea how to pin-point the problem.

When I check the event log on that role, I found the following two errors:

> Application: CacheService.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException
>   Stack:    at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon.AzureUtility.ProcessException(System.Exception)
>   at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Colocatedservice.CacheService.b__0(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

AND

> Faulting application name: CacheService.exe, version: 1.0.4797.0, time
>   stamp: 0x506f41eb Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.2.9200.16451, time stamp: 0x50988aa6 Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x000000000003811c Faulting process id: 0x7b4 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01ce838dfcea8cd3 Faulting application path:
>   E:\plugins\Caching\CacheService.exe Faulting module path:
>   D:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   3b55d5ee-ef81-11e2-93ef-00155d495aa4 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled and reinstalled the Azure Caching package from NuGet.  The file versions were still identical after reinstalling, but the problem was fixed.